# unable to use f_read() and f_lseek() in Fatfs

Tags: spi, fatfs, stm32f0

I'm trying to connect to a 2GB sd card class 6 with stm32f091cctx MCU via SPI. Using fatFs library ver. R0.13a I'm able to mount the drive and open the file with f_mount and f_open functions. But when it comes to reading from file, it just freezes somewhere in f_read function. Also when I try to change the position of pointer with f_lseek, again it freezes. f_lseek works only when I write it as: f_lseek(&MyFile, 0). 
This part of my code is as below:

```
if(FATFS_LinkDriver(&SD_Driver, SDPath) == 0)
{
    f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*)SDPath, 1);
    f_open(&MyFile, "SAMPLE1.WAV", FA_READ);
    f_lseek(&MyFile, 200);
    f_read(&MyFile, rtext, 1000, (UINT*)&bytesread);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably run out of heap size and go to HardFault exception.

You can increase HEAP size from CubeMX -> Project Setting or directly from **_startup.s file.

***PS: Print something in HardFault_Handler and Error_Handler function to see when something goes wrong.***